# How to filter one table if clicks on any row of the another table

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have three tables one is "Sheet1" and others are "sheet2","sheet3".Suppose if clicks on any row of table(i.e. sheet1) it show the relevant data i.e. filtered data corresponding to that row.

Tried using the below, but it is filtering only the common values in two tables.

'''Measure = IF(SELECTEDVALUE(sheet2[CPL]) in VALUES(sheet1[CPL]),1,0)'''

[image: output]

[image: input]

Can someone help on the this

Answer (score 0):

Create relation ships between three tables sheet1, 2, 3

Comment: Here i don't want to use relationship,since by making relationship,iam not getting the actual Sheet2 data since it is filtering out with Date filter i need to get complete if i unselect row in sheet1 table